# Want to remove first and last double quotes from a string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a string which is having multiple double quotes at the beginning and ending of the string like below:

```
""{\"test\":\"{\"Value\":\"Data Source=test\\\\test;Initial Catalog=TestSBe;Integrated Security=True;\"}\"}""
```

I want to remove only one double quote from start and end with the help of angularjs.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless you've omitted the enclosing single quotes or backticks, this is invalid syntax so you will have to fix the source of this invalid syntax.

Comment: Where is that string coming from? Are you sure you only need one quote gone on each end? This looks like masked JSON echoed into HTML/JS?

Comment: I have made JSON.stringfy to that string.

Comment: Why? Where? Again, where is the data coming from? Please show the code that generates / uses that string.

Comment: try now after edit https://stackoverflow.com/a/54198695/10761855

Comment: This string should not exist in the first place. "Solving" this by creating a total mess, then cleaning up the mess is nonsense; the proper way is to avoid the mess.

Comment: @ChrisG I would say it looks like a `JSON.stringlfy()` of a string, not an object.

Comment: @FDavidov Right, that's gotta be it. I'll bet $1000 OP is calling stringify() instead of parse() on an API response.

Comment: @ChrisG, I would also bet the same amount, but if you and me will be bet for the same, who will be paying? The other option is that I bet that you are wrong, and I will most probably end up with $1000 less in my pocket.

Answer (score 4):

Use [String.substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring):

```js
const str = `""{\"test\":\"{\"Value\":\"Data Source=test\\\\test;Initial Catalog=TestSBe;Integrated Security=True;\"}\"}""`

console.log(str.substring(1, str.length - 1))
```

Comment: I'm downvoting this because it completely ignores everything except for the extremely basic question at the outer edge of this glaring XY problem.

Comment: @ChrisG Because going down the rabbit hole of finding out why the string is malformed in the first place is gonna go real good for you. Happy bug hunting.

Answer (score 0):

`.slice` it's shorter method:

```js
const srt = `""{\"test\":\"{\"Value\":\"Data Source=test\\\\test;Initial Catalog=TestSBe;Integrated Security=True;\"}\"}""`.slice(1,-1);
console.log(srt);
```